# R: just installed R on Window 7 but could not create any plots

Tags: r

I just installed the latest R on Window 7. I tried to execute a simple plot command but I got a very weird error.

`Error in dev.hold() : no active or default device`

I suspect that I am missing a graphics device. But I have no idea which graphics device I should use to create a device for plotting ? I used Quartz on my mac but I am not sure if it is also available on Window 7

Comment: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/unable-to-get-plot-in-R-td854044.html

Comment: Did you use the 'vanilla' `.Rprofile` or did you try to use your config files from the Mac?  Please provide details on exactly how you installed `R` and whether you're running from Rgui or the command line, and so on.

Comment: I just downloaded R and ran the exe. I did not use any config files from Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to explicitly set the device to windows.

```
options(device="windows")
```

see [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/options.html) for details